# How to use curl in magento 2 cron?

Tags: magento2, cron, curl

I have cron set up which will run to import the data using the curl. I want to use curl using magento's way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 <?php
  /**
   * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
   * See COPYING.txt for license details.
   */
  declare(strict_types=1);

  namespace Vendor\Module\Cron;

  class GetData {

  protected $curl;

 
  public function __construct(       
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl       
  )
  {   
    $this->curl = $curl;       
  }

  public funnction execute() {
    $this->curl->post($url, $params);
    $result = $this->curl->getBody(); 
  }
}
```